# Decrypting single byte XOR encryption

Tags: cryptography, rust

The code along with the utils module is also at [github](https://github.com/sYnfo/RustCryptopals/blob/master/src/s1c3.rs). If you'd also have any advice on how the whole crate is structured I'd love to hear it. :)

```
use std::ascii::AsciiExt;
use std::str;

use utils::hex_to_bytes;
use s1c2::fixed_xor;

/// Scores ASCII test represented by byte array. The higher the score, the more common
/// English characters the text contains. Letter frequencies are taken from
/// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency.
fn score_text(text: &[u8]) -> f32 {
    let frequencies = "xzqkjupnlgeyihrmfsdcbwaot";
    let text = str::from_utf8(text).unwrap();

    let score: usize = text.chars().map(|letter| {
        frequencies.find(letter.to_ascii_lowercase()).unwrap_or(0)
    }).sum();

    score as f32/text.len() as f32
}

/// Tries to decrypt text encrypted with a single character XOR
/// encryption.
pub fn decrypt_xor(ciphertext: &str) -> Option<(char, String)> {
    let cipherbytes = hex_to_bytes(ciphertext);
    let mut max = 0.0;
    let mut best_solution = None;

    // 32 to 127 should cover printable ASCII characters
    for character in 32..128 {
        let cipher = vec![character; cipherbytes.len()];
        let plaintext = fixed_xor(&cipherbytes, &cipher);
        let score = score_text(&plaintext);
        if score > max {
            max = score;
            best_solution = Some((character as char, String::from_utf8(plaintext).unwrap()));
        }
    }

    best_solution
}

#[test]
fn test_score_text() {
    assert_eq!(score_text(b"x"), 0.0);
    assert_eq!(score_text(b"Z"), 1.0);
    assert_eq!(score_text(b"$"), 0.0);
    assert_eq!(score_text(b"zZz"), 1.0);
}

#[test]
fn test_decrypt_xor() {
    assert_eq!(decrypt_xor("1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736"),
               Some(('X', "Cooking MC's like a pound of bacon".to_string())));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Perform the UTF-8 conversion outside of `score_text`. With a name like `_text`, it should probably accept a `&str` anyway. Note that types are a kind of static assertion about the data; `&str` is a way of saying "UTF-8 encoded bytes". This also helps highlight that the UTF-8 check was being done twice.
2. Use `expect` instead of `unwrap`. When the code fails, you will be thankful.
3. The tracking of the maximum is annoying. Ideally, you'd be able to just say `max_by_key` on the iterator, but `f32`s don't implement `Ord`. There's the possibility of creating a wrapper type that ensures it is never `NaN`, but that feels like overkill here. You could use `max_by`, but that's not currently stable, and would still involve an `unwrap`. Instead, I'd note that all of the strings are the same length here, so dividing them by the length is unnecessary. Adjust the score function to return the previous numerator as a `usize` and then you can use `max_by_key`.
4. Making this change shows that you didn't *just* want "max", you were relying on finding the first one. Evidently, the `max_by_key` algorithm returns the last-most equal value. This causes your tests to fail and pick `x` instead of `X` as the key. You would have seen this problem previously if the key had been `x`. You should probably include spaces in the scoring function. ["In English, the space is slightly more frequent than the top letter (e)"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency).
5. Speaking of the scoring function, it appears to only have **25** characters? And the order doesn't make any sense to me. The highly-recognizable "etaoin" is missing. You may wish to double-check your work there.
6. I'd adjust your tests to assert on the properties of the scoring function that you care about. You don't care about a specific value, you care that:

   - a more-common letter has a higher score than a less-common one
   - ASCII case differences do not change the score
   - unknown letters don't crash
7. This makes me realize that unknown letters will have the same score as 'z', which seems incorrect.

```
use std::ascii::AsciiExt;
use std::str;

use utils::hex_to_bytes;
use s1c2::fixed_xor;

/// Scores ASCII test represented by byte array. The higher the score, the more common
/// English characters the text contains. Letter frequencies are taken from
/// https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Letter_frequency.
fn score_text(text: &str) -> usize {
    let frequencies = "zqxjkvbpygfwmucldrhsnioate ";
    text.chars().map(|letter| {
        frequencies.find(letter.to_ascii_lowercase()).map_or(0, |score| score + 1)
    }).sum()
}

/// Tries to decrypt text encrypted with a single character XOR
/// encryption.
pub fn decrypt_xor(ciphertext: &str) -> Option<(char, String)> {
    let cipherbytes = hex_to_bytes(ciphertext);

    // 32 to 127 should cover printable ASCII characters
    (32..128).map(|character| {
        let cipher = vec![character; cipherbytes.len()];
        let plaintext = fixed_xor(&cipherbytes, &cipher);
        (character as char, String::from_utf8(plaintext).expect("Wasn't UTF-8"))
    }).max_by_key(|a| score_text(&a.1))
}

#[test]
fn test_score_text() {
    assert!(score_text("e") > score_text("x"));
    assert_eq!(score_text("e"), score_text("E"));
    assert!(score_text("$") < score_text("a"));
}

#[test]
fn test_decrypt_xor() {
    assert_eq!(decrypt_xor("1b37373331363f78151b7f2b783431333d78397828372d363c78373e783a393b3736"),
               Some(('X', "Cooking MC's like a pound of bacon".to_string())));
}
```

---

The scoring idea is interesting, but I'm not in love with it. Something with two X shouldn't count the same as one Z. You could probably make better use of the relative frequencies.